# How to decode JSON with unknown field using Gson?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have JSON similar to this :

```
{
  "unknown_field": {
    "field1": "str",
    "field2": "str",
    "field3": "str",
    "field4": "str",
    "field5": "str"
  }, ......
}
```

I created classes to map this json

```
public class MyModel implements Serializable {
  private int id;
  private HashMap<String, Model1> models;

  // getters and setter for id and models here
}
```

and class Model1 is a simple class only with String fields.

But it doesn't work.

**Edit**: the [JSON format](http://textuploader.com/1a0l) looks like this:

```
{
    "1145": {
        "cities_id": "1145",
        "city": "Nawanshahr",
        "city_path": "nawanshahr",
        "region_id": "53",
        "region_district_id": "381",
        "country_id": "0",
        "million": "0",
        "population": null,
        "region_name": "Punjab"
    },
    "1148": {
        "cities_id": "1148",
        "city": "Nimbahera",
        "city_path": "nimbahera",
        "region_id": "54",
        "region_district_id": "528",
        "country_id": "0",
        "million": "0",
        "population": null,
        "region_name": "Rajasthan"
    }, 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just parse it into a Map.

Comment: I did it but no result. This method  - gson.fromJson(json, MyModel.class) returns null

Comment: With "unknown_field", do you mean that the name of this object in the JSON string can vary?

Comment: Because you didn't parse it into a Map.  Gson must have a plain vanilla parser mode that will produce a Map or List without a model class.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

(After OP commented that in fact the [JSON looks like this](http://textuploader.com/1a0l), I completely updated the answer.)

### Solution for Gson 2.0+

I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7618260/56285) that with newer Gson versions this is extremely simple:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Object o = builder.create().fromJson(json, Object.class);
```

The created object is a Map (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap), and if you print it, it looks like this:

```
{1145={cities_id=1145, city=Nawanshahr, city_path=nawanshahr, region_id=53, region_district_id=381, country_id=0, million=0, population=null, region_name=Punjab}, 
 1148={cities_id=1148, city=Nimbahera, city_path=nimbahera, region_id=54, region_district_id=528, country_id=0, million=0, population=null, region_name=Rajasthan}
...
```

### Solution using a custom deserialiser

(**NB**: Turns out you don't really a custom deserialiser unless you're stuck with pre-2.0 versions of Gson. But still it is useful to know how to do [custom deserialisation (and serialisation) in Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization), and it may often be the best approach, depending on how you want to use the parsed data.)

So we're indeed dealing with random / varying field names. (Of course, this JSON format is not very good; this kind of data should be inside a *JSON array*, in which case it could be very easily read into a List. Oh well, we can still parse this.)

First, this is how I would model the JSON data in Java objects:

```
// info for individual city
public class City    {
    String citiesId;
    String city;
    String regionName;
    // and so on
}

// top-level object, containing info for lots of cities
public class CityList  {
    List<City> cities;

    public CityList(List<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

Then, the parsing. One way to deal with this kind of JSON is to create a **custom deserialiser** for the top level object (CityList).

Something like this:

```
public class CityListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CityList> {

    @Override
    public CityList deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
        List<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            // For individual City objects, we can use default deserialisation:
            City city = context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), City.class); 
            cities.add(city);
        }
        return new CityList(cities);
    }

}
```

A key point to notice is the call to **`jsonObject.entrySet()`** which retuns all the top-level fields (with names like "1145", "1148", etc). [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6460364/56285) helped me solve this.

Complete parsing code below. Note that you need to use **`registerTypeAdapter()`** to register the custom serialiser.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(CityList.class, new CityListDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
CityList list = gson.fromJson(json, CityList.class);
```

(Here's a full, [executable example](https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/7862574) that I used for testing. Besides Gson, it uses Guava library.)

Comment: @Nazik: Right, then it's a bit trickier, but solvable using a custom deserialiser. See my edited answer.

Comment: I updated the answer again, as it turned out this is [very simple with newer Gson versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618260/56285). Nice to learn something new about Gson.

Comment: Thanks for a `LinkedTreeMap`. Manual parsing of String values within a JSON object is difficult, but at least it helps.