# How to parse following json using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have seen similar questions about parsing json with dynamic keys, but could not figure out how to parse the following json:

```
{
    "unknown": 
     {
         "id":3980715,
         "name":"namename",
         "profileIconId":28,
         "revisionDate":1451936993000
     }
}
```

Here, the "unknown" key is dynamic, it can be anything. We do not know what it is.

I tried the following class:

```
public class MyResponseClass {
    private Map<String, Object> myResponse;

    //Getter and setter
}
```

But myResponse becomes null after using gson like the following:

```
return gson.fromJson(response, MyResponseClass.class);
```

So, how can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442265/how-to-decode-json-with-unknown-field-using-gson

Comment: It is similar, but i do not think it is the duplicate. I have only object in my response

Comment: The solution to that question solves your question

Comment: I solved it in a different way and posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could manage to parse it like the following:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, MyResponseClass>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, MyResponseClass> map = gson.fromJson(response, mapType);
```

and then iterated over map to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Add an annotation to the field `myResponse`.

```
public class MyResponseClass {
    @SerializedName("unknown")
    private Map<String, Object> myResponse;

    //Getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// String jsonStr = ...;
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> jsonData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
jsonData = (Map<String, Object>)gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Object.class);
```

Your JSON data will be stored in `Map<String, Object>` (which is the simpliest way to store JSON data in Java).

So in this map at `unknown` key you will have another map with `id`, `name` etc.

Comment: 'Map<String, Object> jsonData = (Map<String, Object>)gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Object.class)` is enough