# JSON With Unknown Field in GSON

Tags: gson

The JSON I am trying to parse looks like this:

```
{
   "date": "2018-10-18",
   "rates": {
       "BGN": 1.6999565406,
       "CAD": 1.3045632334,
       "BRL": 3.6899608866
       ...
   }
}
```

I do not know what K-V pairs would be present in the rates object. I want to parse such a JSON structure using GSON, so I created this model class

```
public class Rates {
    public Date date;
}
```

How do I extract the underlying K-V pairs inside rates using GSON?

PS. My question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442265/how-to-decode-json-with-unknown-field-using-gson) as that guy had a varied top-level object. For me, the underlying key-value pairs are dynamic and not known

Answer (score 3):

You may add a new property called `rates` of type `Map<String, Double>` to your `Rates` class. GSON should map those Key-Value pairs to the map without any additional configuration.