# Json to Java - how to access inner objects that have unknown names

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json object of objects and I'm trying to map the inner objects to a Java class.

```
{
"176294012937458694583": {
        "id": "176294012937458694583",
        "description": "Beta",
        "name": "BetaName",
        "account_id": "096382648647"
}
"3428378574582548573293": {
        "id": "3428378574582548573293",
        "description": "Omega",
        "name": "OmegaName",
        "account_id": "32735847382"
}
"4657556334646766874556": {
    "id": "4657556334646766874556",
    "description": "Delta",
    "name": "DeltaName",
    "account_id": "93758598257"
}
}

MyJavaClass 
String id;
String description;
String name;
String accountId;
```

I was hoping to access the inner objects like this & map to MyJavaClass using Gson:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = response.body().getAsJsonObject("176294012937458694583");
MyJavaClass myJavaClass = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), new TypeToken<MyJavaClass>(){}.getType());
```

But the inner objects' memberNames and number of inner objects are unknown until the json data returns. So what would be a better way to access and map these objects to MyJavaClass?

Comment: To clarify, are the top-level keys (`"176294012937458694583"`, `"3428378574582548573293"`, and `"4657556334646766874556"`) unkown, but the keys in the nested objects (`"id"`, `"description"`, `"name"`, and `"account_id"`) all the same?

Comment: you can convert to a `Map<String, MyJavaClass>` where the key is this dynamic id:
`Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, MyJavaClass>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, MyJavaClass> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);` 
after this, you can use `map.values()` and discard the keys

Answer (score 0):

you can deserialise your string input as a map of string keys to MyJavaClass values objects using jackson's ObjectMapper :

```
var value = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputString, new TypeReference<Map<String,MyJavaClass>>(){}););
```

You can then access your objects as follow :

```
value.get("176294012937458694583").getDescription();
```

rmk : for jackson to work properly you have to have a default constructor and explicit getters in MyJavaClass

Comment: I was already working with Gson, but Jackson may have solved my issue too.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by OldProgrammer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442265/how-to-decode-json-with-unknown-field-using-gson) answered my question. The custom serializer with jsonObject.entrySet to access my inner objects was what I needed to properly map to MyJavaClass.