# GSON 2.0+ - Deserialize and parse arbitrary fields

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am pulling a JSON string from a web service, that is styled in the version below. The JSON strings fields for the id's displayed would be arbitrary depending on what was sent in the get. I have followed some examples with gson where they talk about taking the json and running it into an object to handle the arbitrary field values. 
[How to decode JSON with unknown field using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442265/how-to-decode-json-with-unknown-field-using-gson/20442943#20442943) and [Dealing with randomly generated and inconsistent JSON field/key names using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455303/dealing-with-randomly-generated-and-inconsistent-json-field-key-names-using-gson)

My question is, what do I do with the object once I create it to pull out specific fields. I had a custom class to pull the values from the inside of the object (id, name, profile) etc, but I'm lost in how I would be able to reference the two, or  how I would extract the information from the object into an arraylist or something of the sort.

```
{
   "415943": {
      "id": 415943,
      "name": "Zoro Roronoa",
      "profileIconId": 580,
      "revisionDate": 1390848107000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   },
   "19758386": {
      "id": 19758386,
      "name": "Zoro",
      "profileIconId": 535,
      "revisionDate": 1390855130000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   }
}
```

Main.java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object o = gson.fromJson(jsonStatsString, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your custom object that contains the mapped fields in the JSON, and have them converted to a List for you:

```
List<MyObject> items =
                gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() { }.getType());
```

Comment: I keep getting the error `"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2"`

Comment: that's because it looks like the JSON is not an array, but rather an object that contains several objects.  I would just take the string returned and replace the outer {} with [], so that it's an array. Then it should work.

Comment: I didn't end up using the list object, but the `TypeToken` part of your answer is what I was looking for.