# Jackson mapping same JSON nodes with different names as key

Tags: java, android, json, spring, rest

I'm working with a RESTful webservice in android, and I'm using [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) with Jackson for the first time.

I'm using [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) generator to generate the java classes, but I'm in trouble sometimes when an array of the same objects inside JSON have a different names:

```
"a2e4ea4a-0a29-4385-b510-2ca6df65db1c": {
                        "url": "//url1.jpg",
                        "ext": "jpg",
                        "name": "adobe xm0 ",
                        "children": {},
                        "tree_key": []
                    },
                    "d3ff3921-e084-4812-bc49-6a7431b6ce52": {
                        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myvideo",
                        "ext": "video",
                        "name": "youtube example",
                        "children": {},
                        "tree_key": []
                    },
                    "151b5d60-8f41-4f38-8b67-fe875c3f0381": {
                        "url": "https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/something",
                        "ext": "video",
                        "name": "vimeo example",
                        "children": {},
                        "tree_key": []
                    }
```

All the 3 nodes are of the same kind and can be mapped with the same object, but the generator creates 3 classes for each node with different name.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not a JSON array, it's a JSON object. You must be printing out the array as object, thus Jackson puts object hash code as key and value as the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson, you can use `Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(<insert object here>, Map.class);`

as mentioned by [Programmer Bruce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750987/programmer-bruce) : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455303/dealing-with-randomly-generated-and-inconsistent-json-field-key-names-using-gson#comment7592132_6460364)