# Parse jsonObject when field names are unknowm

Tags: java, gson, json

I'm trying to extract some data from a JsonObject.
The problem is that the fields that come inside that json have unpredictable names.

How can I extract that information having this weird field names?

Here is an example:

```
 "myObject":{  
          "216cfa89a2de57554b36b177f0bfbb05":{  

           },
           "0cf9182b5ceba2cb64174141a13e647d":{  

           },
           "eb1d1b19e117ba1387a798d9194b4660":{  

           },
           "157b52871e8e560c7ec0be111ef02363":{  

           },
           "4db69dd3a8ae8e0089bd2959ab0c5f86":{  

           },
}
```

I'm using gson, where we have the method getAsJsonObject, but how can I use it if I don't know the field names?

```
JsonObject jsonObject= myObjectJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("???");
```

Also, there can be a variable number of fields, and this is a problem too. 
I wonder why I don't get an jsonArray as a response, it would be more suitable and I could have parse it that way.

Comment: is `myObject` does not change ?

Comment: it's content changes, the name of the fields and their number is variable

Comment: You could just parse it into a `Map`.

Comment: I mean the name `myObject` does it change or not?

Comment: no, the name doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [JsonObject.entrySet()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#entrySet()).

```
    String json = "{ 'abcd': { 'a':'d' }, 'dcba': { 'd':'a' } }";
    JsonObject o = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

    for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : o.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
```

Or you could get a map when you load the object:

```
    Map<String, JsonObject> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, JsonObject>>(){}.getType());
    for(Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
        System.out.println(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Or you could add a [JsonDeserializer](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) which can deserialize your class into something sensible (likely a map).

Answer (score 0):

In your case its beter to use [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

With JSON like this :

```
{
  "myObject": {
    "216cfa89a2de57554b36b177f0bfbb05": {
      "field1": true
    },
    "0cf9182b5ceba2cb64174141a13e647d": {
      "field2": true
    },
    "eb1d1b19e117ba1387a798d9194b4660": {
      "field3": true
    },
    "157b52871e8e560c7ec0be111ef02363": {
      "field2": true
    },
    "4db69dd3a8ae8e0089bd2959ab0c5f86": {
      "field5": true
    }
  }
}
```

And an expretion of JsonPth

```
$.myObject.*
```

You will get an array of fields

```
[
  {
    "field1": true
  },
  {
    "field2": true
  },
  {
    "field3": true
  },
  {
    "field2": true
  },
  {
    "field5": true
  }
]
```

Hope that help :)

Answer (score -1):

If you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455303/dealing-with-randomly-generated-and-inconsistent-json-field-key-names-using-gson/7618260#7618260) post you see that you can simply do:

`Object o = new Gson().fromJson(json, Object.class);`

The object returned is a Map of String and either String or a Map.

Answer (score -1):

```
JsonObject o = new JsonParser().parse("some json string").getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why this code is different from the code in the question, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.