# Easily parse json with dynamic key values using gson Map class?

Tags: java, json, gson

So I have to work with json can have any value for its keys, so I was searching around and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7618260

```
Object o = new Gson().fromJson(json, Object.class);
```

This seems like the perfect solution, but the only problem is now I have a gson LinkedTreeMap but no idea how to access the values inside. How am I supposed to access the values in this map? Was the answer I viewed earlier wrong? Because he does clearly say gson should support default maps

Comment: Cast `o` to an appropriate `LinkedHashMap` and use its `get` method with an appropriate pair name.

Comment: I just tried `LinkedHashMap linkedMap = (LinkedHashMap)o;` but got `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry. I meant `LinkedTreeMap`.

Comment: Thank worked, thanks