# How to parse list of object from Json Object

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I need help to parse this JSON, i have some problems.

1. The object name is "random"
2. I need to create Java object with list of generic objects and parse Json
3. How i can parse every object with random object name.

The Json to Parse example 1 :

```
{
   "object_name_1":{
      "id":0,
      "value_1":"hello",
      "value_2":"test",

   },
   "object_name_2":{
      "id":1,
      "value_1":"hello",
      "value_2":"test",

   },"object_name_3":{
      "id":2,
      "value_1":"hello",
      "value_2":"test",

   }
}
```

The Json to Parse example 2 :

```
{
   "test_object":{
      "id":0,
      "value_1":"hello",
      "value_2":"test",

   },
   "object_name_2":{
      "id":1,
      "value_1":"hello",
      "value_2":"test",

   },
"new_object":{
      "id":2,
      "value_1":"hello",
      "value_2":"test",

   }
}
```

- NB: This is a JSON Object not Json Array and i have output from API so i can't change Json Output

Thank you.

Comment: answer as always is: iterate the keys (asked so many times that you would find similar question)

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455303/dealing-with-randomly-generated-and-inconsistent-json-field-key-names-using-gson), he has same issue like you, this will help

Comment: You can use [GSON](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) - here is a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format of json is not Appropriate.you can change format and use array for sequential keys. but you can use below approach:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
Iterator<String> keyList = object.keys();

while (keyList.hasNext()){
     String key = keyList.next();
     object.get(key);
     //parse value and use it

}
```