# How can I use auto-value-gson to map unknown json fields

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, auto-value

I am making a simple github gist view app in android that talks with their [api](https://api.github.com/gists/public).

But I am unsure how I can use AutoValue and GSON to map this json response. Do note that I have removed alot of keys since I dont need it currently, the actual
response looks like [this](https://api.github.com/gists/public).

### Example Response

```
[
  {
    "id": "3937809cf12adae05595c43c5ef4ce56",
    "files": {
      "main.css": {
        "filename": "main.css",
        "type": "text/css",
        "language": "CSS",
        "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/*/3937809cf12adae05595c43c5ef4ce56/raw/f46b97a4cf561fa18e50e14bed734eea78bc58d9/main.css",
        "size": 102
      },
      "readme.txt": {
        "filename": "readme.txt",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "language": "Text",
        "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/*/3937809cf12adae05595c43c5ef4ce56/raw/aa7bf7046baaf58b23b4fa4c3b19a575d5eae36e/readme.txt",
        "size": 192
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Question**
I have read that I could map between `String` and `File` object to get it to work. But it does not work since `files` key is or can be an object of objects.

So how can I map these object of unknown objects with auto-value-gson? Is it even possible?

## Code

### GistResponse.java

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class GistResponse {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public abstract String getId();

    @SerializedName("files")
    public abstract FileName getFileNameList();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_GistResponse.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder setId(String value);
        public abstract Builder setFileNameList(FileName value);

        public abstract GistResponse build();
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<GistResponse> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_GistResponse.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

}
```

### FileName.java

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class FileName {

    public abstract Map<String, File> getFilesList();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_FileName.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder setFilesList(Map<String, File> value);
        public abstract FileName build();
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<FileName> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_FileName.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }
}
```

### File.java

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class File {

    @SerializedName("filename")
    public abstract String getFileName();

    @SerializedName("type")
    public abstract String getType();

    @SerializedName("language")
    public abstract String getLanguage();

    @SerializedName("raw_url")
    public abstract String getRawUrl();

    @SerializedName("size")
    public abstract Integer getSize();

    public static Builder builder() { return new AutoValue_File.Builder(); }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder setFileName(String value);
        public abstract Builder setType(String value);
        public abstract Builder setLanguage(String value);
        public abstract Builder setRawUrl(String value);
        public abstract Builder setSize(Integer value);

        public abstract File build();
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<File> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_File.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }
}
```

### Related topics and information:

- [How to decode JSON with unknown field using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442265/how-to-decode-json-with-unknown-field-using-gson#20442943)
- https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson/issues/111
- [Dealing with randomly generated and inconsistent JSON field/key names using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455303/dealing-with-randomly-generated-and-inconsistent-json-field-key-names-using-gson/7618260#7618260)

Answer (score 1):

I have since found a solution which consists of writing a custom `TypeAdapter` which was actually pretty easy.

Here is the code:

```
public class FileTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {}

    @Override
    public List<File> read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            return fileList;
        }

        jsonReader.beginObject();
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

            jsonReader.nextName();

            if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                jsonReader.nextNull();
                continue;
            }

            File.Builder file = File.builder();

            jsonReader.beginObject();
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

                String nextName = jsonReader.nextName();

                switch (nextName) {
                    case "filename": {
                        String nextString = jsonReader.nextString();
                        file.setFileName(nextString);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "type": {
                        String nextString = jsonReader.nextString();
                        file.setType(nextString);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "language": {

                        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                            jsonReader.nextNull();
                        } else {
                            String nextString = jsonReader.nextString();
                            file.setLanguage(nextString);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case "raw_url": {
                        String nextString = jsonReader.nextString();
                        file.setRawUrl(nextString);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "size": {
                        Integer nextInt = jsonReader.nextInt();
                        file.setSize(nextInt);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        jsonReader.skipValue();
                    }
                }
            }
            fileList.add(file.build());
            jsonReader.endObject();
        }
        jsonReader.endObject();
        return fileList;
    }
}
```

Then just annotate the files field in with `@GsonTypeAdapter` inside `GistResponse.java`.

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class GistResponse {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public abstract String getId();

    @GsonTypeAdapter(FileTypeAdapter.class)
    @SerializedName("files")
    public abstract FileName getFileNameList();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_GistResponse.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder setId(String value);
        public abstract Builder setFileNameList(FileName value);

        public abstract GistResponse build();
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<GistResponse> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_GistResponse.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

}
```

And now its possible to parse it.